# FireFox Javascript event handling

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, dom-events

I have the following function that works in Chrome/IE:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        document.all["elems" + i].onscroll = getFunc("onScrollAdj(document.all['tb" + i + "']);");
    }

function getFunc(jsString) {
    return new Function(jsString);
}
```

However I get the error:

> ReferenceError: event is undefined.

I have tried to re-write the function to include an event however I then get another error:

> var i is undefined.

```
document.all["elems" + i].onscroll = onScrollAdj(event, document.all['tb" + i + "');
```

Is there any way to ensure both event and attributes can be passed?

Comment: what is `onScrollAdj` - I bet that has a reference to `event` - which used to be an internet explorer "kludge" that for some reason Chrome decided to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however I get 'ReferenceError: event' is undefined.

That's because you're trying to use `event` without declaring it as an argument. That only works on Microsoft browsers, which make `event` a global, and Chrome which throws a bone to Microsoft-only code. You will need to declare the argument.

There's no need for `new Function` virtually ever, and certainly not in this case:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    document.all["elems" + i].onscroll = getFunc(i);
    // ------------------------------------------^
}

function getFunc(i) {
// --------------^
    return function(event) { onScrollAdj(event, document.all['tb' + i]); };
    // -------------^--------------------^
}
```

Note that you'll have to ensure that `onScrollAdj` accepts `event`:

```
function onScrollAdj(event, tbThingy) {
// ------------------^
```